# AttributeError when attempting to generate a report with ydata-profiling in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis, python-venv, data-profiling

I am attempting to generate a data profiling report using the `ydata-profiling` library in Python. Upon executing the following code:

```py
import ydata_profiling

profile = ydata_profiling.ProfileReport(df_accidentes)
profile.to_file("report.html")
```

I encounter the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cbook' has no attribute 'mplDeprecation'
```

Here is the complete traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\ETL+EDA.ipynb Celda 5 line 2
      1 profile = ydata_profiling.ProfileReport(df_accidentes)
----> 2 profile.to_file("report.html")

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\typeguard\__init__.py:1033, in typechecked.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
   1031 memo = _CallMemo(python_func, _localns, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
   1032 check_argument_types(memo)
-> 1033 retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
   1034 try:
   1035     check_return_type(retval, memo)

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\profile_report.py:355, in ProfileReport.to_file(self, output_file, silent)
    352         self.config.html.assets_prefix = str(output_file.stem) + "_assets"
    353     create_html_assets(self.config, output_file)
--> 355 data = self.to_html()
    357 if output_file.suffix != ".html":
    358     suffix = output_file.suffix

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\typeguard\__init__.py:1033, in typechecked.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
   1031 memo = _CallMemo(python_func, _localns, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
   1032 check_argument_types(memo)
-> 1033 retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
   1034 try:
   1035     check_return_type(retval, memo)

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\profile_report.py:470, in ProfileReport.to_html(self)
    462 def to_html(self) -> str:
    463     """Generate and return complete template as lengthy string
    464         for using with frameworks.
    465 
   (...)
    468 
    469     """
--> 470     return self.html

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\typeguard\__init__.py:1033, in typechecked.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
   1031 memo = _CallMemo(python_func, _localns, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
   1032 check_argument_types(memo)
-> 1033 retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
   1034 try:
   1035     check_return_type(retval, memo)

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\profile_report.py:277, in ProfileReport.html(self)
    274 @property
    275 def html(self) -> str:
    276     if self._html is None:
--> 277         self._html = self._render_html()
    278     return self._html

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\typeguard\__init__.py:1033, in typechecked.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
   1031 memo = _CallMemo(python_func, _localns, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
   1032 check_argument_types(memo)
-> 1033 retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
   1034 try:
   1035     check_return_type(retval, memo)

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\profile_report.py:385, in ProfileReport._render_html(self)
    382 def _render_html(self) -> str:
    383     from ydata_profiling.report.presentation.flavours import HTMLReport
--> 385     report = self.report
    387     with tqdm(
    388         total=1, desc="Render HTML", disable=not self.config.progress_bar
    389     ) as pbar:
    390         html = HTMLReport(copy.deepcopy(report)).render(
    391             nav=self.config.html.navbar_show,
    392             offline=self.config.html.use_local_assets,
   (...)
    400             version=self.description_set.package["ydata_profiling_version"],
    401         )

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\typeguard\__init__.py:1033, in typechecked.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
   1031 memo = _CallMemo(python_func, _localns, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
   1032 check_argument_types(memo)
-> 1033 retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
   1034 try:
   1035     check_return_type(retval, memo)

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\profile_report.py:271, in ProfileReport.report(self)
    268 @property
    269 def report(self) -> Root:
    270     if self._report is None:
--> 271         self._report = get_report_structure(self.config, self.description_set)
    272     return self._report

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\typeguard\__init__.py:1033, in typechecked.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
   1031 memo = _CallMemo(python_func, _localns, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
   1032 check_argument_types(memo)
-> 1033 retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
   1034 try:
   1035     check_return_type(retval, memo)

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\profile_report.py:253, in ProfileReport.description_set(self)
    250 @property
    251 def description_set(self) -> BaseDescription:
    252     if self._description_set is None:
--> 253         self._description_set = describe_df(
    254             self.config,
    255             self.df,
    256             self.summarizer,
    257             self.typeset,
    258             self._sample,
    259         )
    260     return self._description_set

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\model\describe.py:137, in describe(config, df, summarizer, typeset, sample)
    135 missing_map = get_missing_active(config, table_stats)
    136 pbar.total += len(missing_map)
--> 137 missing = {
    138     name: progress(get_missing_diagram, pbar, f"Missing diagram {name}")(
    139         config, df, settings
    140     )
    141     for name, settings in missing_map.items()
    142 }
    143 missing = {name: value for name, value in missing.items() if value is not None}
    145 # Sample

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\model\describe.py:138, in <dictcomp>(.0)
    135 missing_map = get_missing_active(config, table_stats)
    136 pbar.total += len(missing_map)
    137 missing = {
--> 138     name: progress(get_missing_diagram, pbar, f"Missing diagram {name}")(
    139         config, df, settings
    140     )
    141     for name, settings in missing_map.items()
    142 }
    143 missing = {name: value for name, value in missing.items() if value is not None}
    145 # Sample

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\utils\progress_bar.py:11, in progress.<locals>.inner(*args, **kwargs)
      8 @wraps(fn)
      9 def inner(*args, **kwargs) -> Any:
     10     bar.set_postfix_str(message)
---> 11     ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
     12     bar.update()
     13     return ret

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\model\missing.py:112, in get_missing_diagram(config, df, settings)
    109 if len(df) == 0:
    110     return None
--> 112 result = handle_missing(settings["name"], settings["function"])(config, df)
    113 if result is None:
    114     return None

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\model\missing.py:88, in handle_missing.<locals>.inner(*args, **kwargs)
     78             warnings.warn(
     79                 f"""There was an attempt to generate the {missing_name} missing values diagrams, but this failed.
     80 To hide this warning, disable the calculation
   (...)
     84 (include the error message: '{error}')"""
     85             )
     87         try:
---> 88             return fn(*args, *kwargs)
     89         except ValueError as e:
     90             warn_missing(name, str(e))

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\multimethod\__init__.py:328, in multimethod.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    326 func = self[tuple(func(arg) for func, arg in zip(self.type_checkers, args))]
    327 try:
--> 328     return func(*args, **kwargs)
    329 except TypeError as ex:
    330     raise DispatchError(f"Function {func.__code__}") from ex

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\model\pandas\missing_pandas.py:16, in pandas_missing_bar(config, df)
     13 @missing_bar.register
     14 def pandas_missing_bar(config: Settings, df: pd.DataFrame) -> str:
     15     notnull_counts = len(df) - df.isnull().sum()
---> 16     return plot_missing_bar(
     17         config,
     18         notnull_counts=notnull_counts,
     19         nrows=len(df),
     20         columns=list(df.columns),
     21     )

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\contextlib.py:80, in ContextDecorator.__call__.<locals>.inner(*args, **kwds)
     78 @wraps(func)
     79 def inner(*args, **kwds):
---> 80     with self._recreate_cm():
     81         return func(*args, **kwds)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\contextlib.py:144, in _GeneratorContextManager.__exit__(self, typ, value, traceback)
    142 if typ is None:
    143     try:
--> 144         next(self.gen)
    145     except StopIteration:
    146         return False

File c:\Users\Compumar\Documents\Henry\PI_DA\PI_DA\.venv\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\visualisation\context.py:85, in manage_matplotlib_context()
     83 deregister_matplotlib_converters()  # revert to original unit registries
     84 with warnings.catch_warnings():
---> 85     warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=matplotlib.cbook.mplDeprecation)
     86     matplotlib.rcParams.update(originalRcParams)

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cbook' has no attribute 'mplDeprecation'
```

I have tried looking through the documentation and searching for a solution, but have come up short. Here are the versions of the relevant libraries I am using as per `pip list`:

- ydata-profiling: 4.5.1
- matplotlib: 3.8.0

Additionally, I am using a virtual environment (`venv`) for this project, not Conda, as I saw in some other questions.

Has anyone come across this issue before or have any suggestions on how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I initially suspected that the error might be due to a version mismatch between ydata-profiling and matplotlib, so I tried using different versions of matplotlib, but the error persisted. I also considered that there might be a missing dependency or a conflict with another library, so I checked the ydata-profiling documentation for any specific version requirements or known issues, but didn't find anything relevant.

I was expecting the profile.to_file("report.html") line to generate a HTML report file summarizing the data in df_accidentes. However, instead, I encountered an AttributeError relating to matplotlib.cbook.

I searched StackOverflow for similar issues, particularly focusing on any AttributeError instances with ydata-profiling or matplotlib, but most of the questions were related to different errors or were using Conda instead of venv.

I haven't been able to find a solution that resolves this error yet, which is why I am seeking help here. I am wondering if there might be a known issue or a workaround to get the ydata-profiling library to generate the report as expected.

Comment: https://github.com/ydataai/ydata-profiling/issues/1455

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, I followed these steps:

- I removed my old virtual environment and created a new one.
- I installed the dependencies from the requirements.txt file in the ydata-profiling project.
- I installed ydata-profiling and the other libraries I needed.

Somehow that worked out just fine...